# Grabbing a string using regex

Tags: regex, groovy

I have the following string. I have broken it into two lines below for clarity but they are one line.

```
    WHEN NVL(somevar1, 0) > 0 THEN 
(CAST(NVL(somevar2, 0) AS
 FLOAT(53)) / CAST(NVL(somevar3, 0) AS FLOAT(53))) * 100
```

I want to write a Regex so that I can get somevar1, somevar2 and somevar3.

I was trying with something like this:

```
NVL(.*,)
```

But this matches the last comma instead of the first comma.

BTW, I am doing this in groovy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'd help to know what regex engine you're using, as not all support non-greedy quantifiers.

Try one of the following:

```
NVL\((.*?),
```

or

```
NVL\(([^,]*),
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `NVL\((\w+?),`

Comment: SilentGhost -- quite possibly, but I've even run into regex engines that didn't support it, as sad as that is.  Also, I probably should've mentioned that mine's still greedy in a way -- it could include spaces on either side of the variable name (more like Drake's original), while using \w might require \s* on either side, or a post-match trim.

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt is a greedy regex. Try `/NVL\((.*?),/` and the results should be in backreference 1.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `\w` ( or possibly `[\w_$]` ) instead of `*` so as to match 'word characters' (letters, digits)

Comment: you're mixing quantifiers and classes.